# Calculating the union of 2 longitudal intervals (that may wrap around 180 degrees)

Tags: union, geospatial, angle, intervals

The story:

I have a `LatLongBounds` class that represents an area on the surface of the earth by a latitudinal interval (bounded by north & south - not important to this question) and a longitudinal interval (bounded by east and west; both normalized to a range [-180, 180] - negative being a westerly direction).

In order to be able to represent an area that straddles the 180 degree meridian the value of west may be set to be greater than east (eg. the range west = 170, east = -170 will straddle said meridian).  In effect the longitudinal interval may wrap around at 180 degrees (or equivalently -180 degrees).

My Question:

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can calculate the minimum union of two longitudinal intervals that may wrap around at 180 degrees.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is which "direction" to you want to consider your "area". With your example (170E,170W), this is a smaller area if you consider the range to be between a and b, but a large area if you consider the area between b and a. Will the coordinates always be given in the same order?

By "minimum union", do you mean the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29)?

You might consider changing your coordinate system while you are doing these calculations, adding 180 degrees to all coordinates in one of the hemispheres, and always "traveling" in the same direction.

Comment: Because the valid range wraps at 180/-180, there can be two solutions to the union of two intervals.  For example the union of the intervals [-180,-170] and [170, 180] can be [-180, 180] or [170, -170]; I'd refer to the latter as the minimum union.  The interval is always described as [western border, eastern border] to allow me to represent an interval straddling the dateline (180 degree meridian).

Comment: I think this is a terminology issue... Can you give more details as to the application of these calculations, that would help solve the problem.

Comment: I'm basically trying to implement a version of [GLatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLngBounds) from the Google Maps API.  In my particular use-case, I'm trying to view the area of the globe bounded by the 2 or more areas that may straddle the 180 degree meridian. A non-minimum union usually ends up zooming out to view the entire globe, even though the actual area covered may be quite small.  It's definitely a special case so for now I just use a non-minimum union calculation.